# Clearfix Stops Word Wrap

Tags: css, html, clearfix

I had to apply a clearfix to my list items in order for a border to wrap around my floats, but once I added the clearfix, it caused a wordwrap I had applied to the list to stop working and now long URLs extend the div into other divs.

If anyone could help with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. The issue can be viewed here: http://www.noellesnotes.com (Tweets section of the footer).

Here;s the relevant code:

HTML

```
<div id="tweets">
    <ul>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <p class="tweet">The tweet.</p>
            <p class="timePosted">TIME</p>
            <p class="interact">INTERACT LINKS</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tweet, .tweet a, .tweet span, .interact a{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Georgia, sans-serif;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.timePosted{
    width:40%;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.interact{
    width:60%;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.interact a{
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Arvo', Georgia;
}

#tweets ul{
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#tweets ul li{
    border: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {   /* for IE/Mac */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: lol. Good question... This clearfix was suggested to me by another stackoverflow user... Crossing all the ts. lol.

Comment: We'll, it's certainly out-of-date info. Now I use :after {content: ''; display: table; clear: both;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
#tweets ul li { width: 100%; }
```

Solved the issue for me :)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Don't forget to accept if you're all set here :)